# WebAPIのレスポンスボディに含むマスターの情報はIDかIDに紐づく値か

Tags: webapi

WebAPIのレスポンスボディにマスターのデータを入れるとき、IDとIDに紐づく値のどちらを返すのがよいのでしょうか？

例えば、あるタスクを取得するGET /tasks/1 のようなWebAPIのレスポンスボディの場合、ステータスのidとnameはどちらを返すのがよいのでしょうか？

#### レスポンスボディのサンプル

```js
{
 "id": 1,
 "status": {
  "id": 2, // どっちがよい？
  "name": "進行中" // どっちがよい？
}
```

#### statusマスターテーブル

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 完了 |
| 2 | 進行中 |
| 3 | 未完了 |

Answer (score 1):

提示された例から ToDo リストのようなものかと想像しましたが、個人的には id = 数値で返す形式は (利用する側視点で) 分かりづらいと感じます。

最終的には設計の方向性次第かと思いますが、類似の API を参考にしてみるのも一つの方法です。
Microsoft Graph API では以下の通り、状態を表す文字列を返すようです。

[todoTask resource type - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/todotask?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

> | **Property** | **Type** | **Description** |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | status | taskStatus | Indicates the state or progress of the task. Possible values are: `notStarted`, `inProgress`, `completed`, `waitingOnOthers`, `deferred`. |

もしくは、もっと単純に "完了か否か" のトグルであれば、Remember The Milk では completed というフィールドを用意しています。

[Remember The Milk - Services / API / Tasks](https://www.rememberthemilk.com/services/api/tasks.rtm)

> ```xml
>         <task id="815784" due="" has_due_time="0"
>         added="2015-05-08T13:52:26Z" completed="" deleted=""
>         priority="2" postponed="0" estimate="" />
> ```

Answer (score 1):

状況次第です。

・ APIを使うのは誰か。内部だけでしか使わないのか、サードパーティも使うのかとか。
・APIで得られた結果はどのように使われるのか。プログラムで扱うだけなのか、人間に表示されるのか。後者なのだとしたら多言語対応が必要か。

などなど。

数字がわかりやすい場面もあるしそうでない場面もあります。要件次第ではどちらか一方が自明に決まる場合もあるでしょう。例えば結果を素通しでエンドユーザーに表示する機能しかフロントエンドにないなら自明にメッセージを返さないといえけません。